# Can you delete an OST file?

Tags: outlook, office365

I know an ost file is an offline outlook data file so you can view your emails etc if you're not connected to the internet. But if you delete an ost file whilst you're still connected to the internet. Will Office 365 automatically download another ost file for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Outlook will rebuild it when it starts up the next time.